# Mysql.Data and Azure Mysql error 'Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist'

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-mysql-database

When I try to execute the stored procedure against Azure MySQL version 8.0.15 server using following code I get the error saying 'Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist'. This error does not happen with older versions. some search says to use MySQL_upgrade but I don't get that to work against azure MySQL. How do I overcome this error? Everything works fine when I connect to local MySQL version which is same as azure hosted.

Sample code

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = "myserver.mysql.database.azure.com",
            Database = "mydb",
            UserID = "myserver@myserver",
            Password = "password",
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.Prefered,
        };

        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Opening connection");
            await conn.OpenAsync();

            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "prc_myprocedure";

                var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.Default);
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Closing connection");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Complete error:

```
Unhandled exception. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'mysql.proc' doesn't exist
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetProcedures(String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetProcedures(String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetSchemaInternal(String collection, String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetSchema(String collection, String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.GetSchemaCollection(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcData(MySqlConnection connection, String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.AddNew(MySqlConnection connection, String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcedure(MySqlConnection conn, String spName, String cacheKey)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetParameters(String procName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.CheckParameters(String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at AzureMySqlExample.MySqlUpdate.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\sammo\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs:line 31
   at AzureMySqlExample.MySqlUpdate.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Comment: I think to execute mysql stored procedures we have to use 
 "call command .e.g, "call procedurename(parameters) "in command text

Comment: This issue has been raised to the product group but wanted to see if this is still an issue or if you were able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE:** You are getting the below error because when you start a connection to Azure MySQL, the gateway of Azure MySQL will first send back a greeting package with a default server version "5.6.42.0 MySQL Community Server (GPL)". This make the MySQL.Data driver treat the server version as 5.6. But actually it is 8.0 and in MySQL 8.0, the table mysql.proc not exists anymore.

**Workaround:** You can use ProxySQL to fix the version issue:

1. Set up ProxySQL for Azure MySQL
   https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Database-for-MySQL/Load-balance-read-replicas-using-ProxySQL-in-Azure-Database-for/ba-p/880042
2. Update the server version in ProxySQL
   Connecting to ProxySQL with admin account, run the following commands.

a.  mysql –u admin –padmin -h 127.0.0.1 -P 6032

b.  UPDATE global_variables SET variable_value='' WHERE variable_name='mysql-server_version';

c.  load mysql variables to runtime;

d.  save mysql variable to disk;

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mike Ubezzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9454112/mike-ubezzi)'s answer (credit to this [post](https://www.nopcommerce.com/fr/boards/topic/88906/table-mysqlproc-doesnt-exist-with-new-install#285942) to point me in the right direction), the solution was to simply change the port from 3306 to 3309 in the database connection string. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-supported-versions#connect-to-a-gateway-node-that-is-running-a-specific-mysql-version).

In my case, I was running an ASP.NET app linked to a MySQL database version 8.0.  After editing the connection string in the web app's configuration settings and restarting the web app, my stored procedures executed as expected.